# alignat: equation rows with different numbers of alignment columns

Tags: align, amsmath, alignat

The below is close to what I want, using `alignat` with 2 pairs of right-left-aligned columns:

1. right-aligned `\sigma` and `y`
2. left-aligned distribution names `LogNormal` and `Normal`
3. empty right-aligned column
4. left-aligned location parameters `0` and `\beta_1` etc.

But the distribution names have different lengths (`LogNormal` vs `Normal`) so I would prefer to only start aligning the location parameters starting with the second line (`\beta_1` etc.). I wonder if this is possible, since it essentially would mean changing the numbers of alignment columns across the rows, correct ?

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\sigma &\sim \text{LogNormal}(&&0, 1) \\
y &\sim \text{Normal}(&&\beta_1 \\
& &&+ \beta_2 \\
& &&+ \beta_3, \\
& && \sigma )
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

vs what I want, which I can obtain in a super hacky way like:

```
\begin{align*}
\sigma &\sim \text{LogNormal}(0, 1) \\
y &\sim \text{Normal}(\beta_1 \\
& \hspace{1.7cm} + \beta_2 \\
& \hspace{1.7cm} + \beta_3, \\
& \hspace{1.7cm} \sigma )
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\sigma &\sim \operatorname{LogNormal}(0, 1) \\
y &\sim \operatorname{Normal}(
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  & \beta_1 \\
  & + \beta_2 \\
  & + \beta_3, \\
  & \sigma )
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `\operatorname` rather than `\text`.